# How to replicate user from LDAP to application database for handling authorization from application layer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, authorization, jhipster, spring-ldap

Hi I am not pretty sure about the LDAP and spring security. I have a requirement were as the application authentication has to be carried out by a LDAP and authorization mechanism has to handled by application layer. I am using Jhipster which has spring security implementation. However, I can able to connect to LDAP and authenticate the user.

Now authorization mechanism has to be handled by application layer where I could manage authorities. So I thought of replicating the user information from the LDAP to application layer database if the user is not present just after the user authentication process. So how can I implement this with spring security framework. How to intercept the filter chain or some process to do this.

And finally is this the good approach or is there a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I implemented LDAP authentication and local Authorization in my project.

**Configuration:**

```
<beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="authenticator">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <beans:property name="userSearch">
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                    <beans:constructor-arg name="searchBase"
                        value="ou=example,dc=springframework,dc=org" />
                    <beans:constructor-arg name="searchFilter"
                        value="(uid={0})" />
                    <beans:constructor-arg name="contextSource"
                        ref="contextSource" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="authoritiesPopulator"
        ref="myLDAPAuthPopulator" />
</beans:bean>


<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

**Custom Authorities Populator:**

```
@Component("myLDAPAuthPopulator")
public class MyLdapAuthoritiesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(
        DirContextOperations userData, String username) {

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    User user = userDao.searchUser(username);

    List<String> roleList = userDao.getRoles(username);
    if (!roleList.isEmpty()) {
         for (String role : roleList) {
            System.out.println(role);
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
    } 
    return authorities;
}
```

Comment: Hi amanth how you are replicating user to your application database. I require some code to do that. And where you are intercept/add this user replication code.

Comment: You should insert this code in the authorities populator because the spring will hit this class only after LDAP authentication. This way you will be sure that the user exists in the LDAP. One way to do this is to assign roles and additional data by inserting an else part where we are checking whether the roleList is empty or not.

Comment: The code that you have provided is used to add additional authorities. But in my case i have to create user in my application specific db. So all the information about the user will be fetched and managed from application layer like authorities/User info. I am wandering about where we to put my code just after authentication from LDAP to create a user if user is not there in application db.

Comment: You can add this user in the database if the searchUser function returns null .